# A Better (Hopefully) JavaScript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript

In our application, we have a need for a robust countdown timer.  When the timer counts down to zero, we move the user on to the next page.

There are a LOT of questions on here about making a countdown timer in JavaScript. I've weeded through a lot of them, looked at a lot of the code samples, tried a lot of plugins, and all of them fail for this one test case:  If you adjust your computers system clock, all of these timers mess up (gain time, lose time, or just freeze). The reason is that most of them base their logic on saving some initial start time and then at some interval (either via setTimeout or setInterval) getting the current time and doing a diff between it and the start time.  When you adjust your system time, the "current" time can be an hour or days before your start time, or hours or days later.

So, I've come up with the following code to try to handle these system change scenarios. The main thing I do is check if the "diff" between my start and current is negative (or greater than roughly one hour to handle an automatic daylight savings adjustment) to just use the tick interval as an approximation. Also, reset the start time to be current time on each tick, so that elapsed time is the sum of the time between differences, not just the diff between an initial start time and current time. Anyone see any flaws with this approach?

```
var timeLeft = 60000, // time left in ms, 1 minute for this example
    startTime, 
    totalElapsedTime = 0,
    TICK_INTERVAL = 500; // the setTimeout interval


var timerTick = function () {

    var now = new Date(),
        elapsedTime = now.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    // if the elapsed time was positive and less than approximately an hour, then add the elapsed time to the total
    // otherwise, add the TICK_INTERVAL, which we know is the theoretical minimum between timerTick() calls

    totalElapsedTime = (elapsedTime > 0 && elapsedTime < 3590000) ? totalElapsedTime + elapsedTime : totalElapsedTime + TICK_INTERVAL;

    // reset start time 
    startTime = now;

    // there is time left, so set up another tick
    if (totalElapsedTime < timeLeft) {

        // update the html that is displaying remaining time

        setTimeout(timerTick, TICK_INTERVAL);          

    }
    else {

        // time ran out, so do whatever you do when it runs out            

    }
}


// start the timer
startTime = new Date();
setTimeout(timerTick, TICK_INTERVAL);
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply doing a `setInterval` for 1 second and decreasing a counter each time the function is called?

Comment: If you want to try something a bit different, you could just query the time from server using some AJAX call or something. I guess the server time can be guaranteed to stay somewhat static (except for certain very special cases).

Comment: I considered that, but we are showing the timer to the user and the seconds are counting down.  I would worry if the ajax called were delayed for some reason, that the user would see the timer freeze or jump down.

Comment: No need to worry, `setInterval` will be called exactly (more or less) at the interval you specify. Even if the AJAX call takes 5000 ms for example, your function will be called 5 times (possibly overlapping in this example).

Comment: Of course, you never make AJAX calls synchronously so that's not a real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why does the following not work for you?

```
var timeleft = 60000,
    tick = 1000,
    intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
        timeleft = timeleft - tick;
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            // clear the interval
            clearInterval(intervalID);

            // do something
        }
    }, tick);
```

**Update**

Using `setTimeout` (this will drift, but probably be ok unless you are using it for animation):

```
var timeleft = 60000,
    tick = 1000;

window.setTimeout(function timerFn() {
    timeleft = timeleft - tick;
    if (timeleft > 0) {
        // set the next timeout
        setTimeout(timerFn, tick);
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}, tick);
```

Comment: `setInterval` does not mean your function will run at exactly the interval you specify.  All it does is add your function call to the execution queue and it will run as soon as all other executing code has run.  In reality, this means your function will run more than a second later, so the timer will drift using this logic.

Comment: Not exactly, every call to your function will be scheduled at a fixed interval so even if your function takes 500 ms for example, the next call to the function will be at previous time + tick (so 500 ms later). So there will be a little bit of drift (which is unavoidable no matter what approach you take) but it will be local (between function calls) only. It will not affect future calls.

Comment: I'm showing the seconds counting down visually to the user. Therefore, the interval needs to be less than 1000 or else the timer will appear to "skip" to the user. Using setInterval causes problems because it relentlessly adds function calls.  The case for using setTimeout is more eloquently explained here: http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/.

Comment: You actually want to use setInterval here, not setTimeout because setInterval does NOT care how long your function takes. It will never deviate from the initial interval you give it. I made an example here to prove that even if your function takes longer than the interval, you will get called again and the interval ALWAYS fires exactly at the right time: http://jsbin.com/ayoduy/1/

Comment: Make sure you open the console in the jsbin example to see the current time (seconds value) and the interval time left being printed. There's no skipping that happens even though I'm doing a bunch of useless computations further down in the function. Hope this helps.

Comment: One final clarification. As the article you linked to shows, setInterval will deviate (within a few ms) to when the actual function is called. That absolutely does not make a difference if you are using the interval to capture/display something on a timed basis though since no human eye will tell the difference.

Comment: It can be bad for multiple calls to timerTick to be scheduled via setInterval. In my case, I'm doing some things such as saving when the time runs out.  I would not want the time ran out code to run multiple times, and it would be more difficult to prevent that using setInterval.  With the setTimeout method, you can guarantee that logic will not run because you don't make another setTimeout call.

Comment: You can easily work around that by creating the timeRanOut function only once and having access to it from your closure. Or run it and set it back to `undefined`. There are plenty of options either way but you can easily update my example above to use `setTimeout` as well. I'll do that in a sec as an example.